# Disable Form Submit button if Password and confirm password field not filled

Tags: sitecore-forms, validation

[image]

I am trying to disable submit button if 2 fields i.e `Password` and `Confirm Password` are not filled.

However when I am trying to add condition I see Password fields are disabled and I cannot select them in condition dropdown.

How to achieve this scenario?

Comment: Include screenshots from your setup in the question. Also with conditions how you configured them so far.

Comment: Added the screenshot . The password fields are disable not able to select in order to apply condition on submit button

Comment: You can also refer to this document to customize. https://smartsitecore.com/en/call-custom-javascript-on-sitecore-forms-submit/ @Aditya

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Sitecore has blocked adding conditions that include the password controls out of the box.

Im guessing this is because they have there own in built conditions that are attached to those controls, these check that the length of the field is greater than 6 characters and also that the password field matches the confirmation field.

There doesnt however appear to be a condition that stops it submitting if empty.

You should be able to achieve what you require by creating a custom submit button. To do this, navigate to **\Views\FormBuilder\FieldTemplates** in your sitecore solution.

Duplicate the file **Button.cshtml** and add the following:

```
<script>
$("[name$=Value]").on( "keyup", function() {
  if($("input[name$=Value]").val() && $("input[name$=ConfirmPassword]").val())
  {
    $(".custom-submit").prop('disabled', false);
  }else{
        $(".custom-submit").prop('disabled', true);
  }
} );
$("[name$=ConfirmPassword]").on( "keyup", function() {
  if($("input[name$=Value]").val() && $("input[name$=ConfirmPassword]").val())
  {
    $(".custom-submit").prop('disabled', false);
  }else{
        $(".custom-submit").prop('disabled', true);
  }
} );
</script>
```

In addition to to this, add a class called "custom-submit" and also disabled to the end of input tag.
i.e. `<input ... type="submit" class="custom-submit @cssClass" ...   disabled />`

To start using this custom submit button in your sitecore form you need to overwrite the existing Checkbox to use new view (not recommended - but good for quick test purposes locally). Or create a new field by duplicating the existing and adding your new view.

See here: `/sitecore/system/Settings/Forms/Field Types/Structure/Submit Button`

[image: Custom Submit Button]

Answer (score 0):

Adding some more information with the answer to what I discovered about why the Password and Confirm Password fields are disabled in the Edit condition. When I checked that how this condition dialogue is being created, what I found is it is created from the below file

`\wwwroot\<your-sitecore-instance>\sitecore\shell\client\Applications\FormsBuilder\Layouts\Renderings\ConditionsEditor\ConditionsEditor.cshtml`

And the JS where the logic is written is in the below location.

`\wwwroot\<your-sitecore-instance>\sitecore\shell\client\Applications\FormsBuilder\Layouts\Renderings\ConditionsEditor\ConditionsEditor.js`

Under this JS, I found that there is a method that is setting the condition drop-down like below.

```
setFormFields: function(formFields, pageFieldTypes) {
    var pageIdx = 0,
        fieldKeysMapping = {},
        conditionFieldsList = [],
        actionFieldsList = [],
        disabledFieldTypes = this.DisabledFieldTypes;
```

When I see what is set in the variable (using `console.log`) called `disabledFieldTypes`, I found that there are four controls that are not able to select in the condition drop down. Here are those.

```
{7E9A0903-A52C-4843-BBE1-5B26BD162BED} => File Upload
{668A1C37-9D6B-483B-B7C1-340C92D04BA4} => Password
{6293530F-36A1-4CA6-A2E6-C59C9343F096} => Password Confirmation
{72B22999-8509-49A1-BD0C-04D68A9131CD} => Email Confirmation
```

And they are getting disabled by this code.

```
if (_.contains(disabledFieldTypes, item.model.fieldTypeItemId)) {
    var disabledField = {
        itemId: field.itemId,
        name: field.name,
        pageId: field.pageId,
        disabled: true
    };
    conditionFieldsList.push(disabledField);
    } else {
        conditionFieldsList.push(field);
    }
```

I didn't find where Sitecore has set this internally but there is no sense to change the functionality.

So Yes I agree with @Dean to do some customizations via javascript code in your custom button control to make it disable.

Here is an article that I found where they are handling some situations using JavaScript code on the custom button control. So you can refer to it.

https://smartsitecore.com/en/call-custom-javascript-on-sitecore-forms-submit/

Hope this will give you some context on this.